# Closing Custom Dialog Box

Tags: java, android, dialog

I am Using the following code for my custom dialog box.

[Code is here](https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog)

I am using a new layout by setCustomView Method.That layout contains a 'Ok' button and a '`Cancel`' button.

I need to close the dialog box when click on cancel.

```
buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d("onClick" , "YYYYY");
                        //up to this comes , here what I can wright
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please show full code.

Comment: @shree202 : https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog ful code is here

Comment: Not the code on github, but that you tried.

Comment: I am using the same code in the github, am just added an onclicklistener , you may please look at that code and what their can do to dismiss?

Comment: Please post your code of custom xml and activity code wich contains above code.

Answer (score 0):

dialogObject.dismiss();

You can use this method

Answer (score 0):

Why not you create custom dialog from here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Very clearly explained and easy to implement too.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Log.d("onClick" , "YYYYY");

                     qustomDialogBuilder.dismiss();//this line will close the dialog

                  }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `TestDialogActivity` like below,

```
public class TestDialogActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String HALLOWEEN_ORANGE = "#FF7F27";
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    private OnClickListener mShowDialogClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            QustomDialogBuilder qustomDialogBuilder = new QustomDialogBuilder(
                    v.getContext())
                    .setTitle("Set IP Address")
                    .setTitleColor(HALLOWEEN_ORANGE)
                    .setDividerColor(HALLOWEEN_ORANGE)
                    .setMessage("You are now entering the 10th dimension.")
                    .setCustomView(R.layout.example_ip_address_layout,
                            v.getContext())
                    .setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            alertDialog=qustomDialogBuilder.create();
            qustomDialogBuilder.setAlertDialog(alertDialog);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(mShowDialogClickListener);
    }
```

and replace `setCustomView` of `QustomDialogBuilder` like below

```
public QustomDialogBuilder setCustomView(int resId, final Context context) {
        View customView = View.inflate(context, resId, null);
        ((TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.ip_text)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ((FrameLayout)mDialogView.findViewById(R.id.customPanel)).addView(customView);
        return this;
    }
```

finally add below line into your `QustomDialogBuilder`

`private AlertDialog alertDialog;
 public void setAlertDialog(AlertDialog alertDialog)
    {
        this.alertDialog=alertDialog;
    }`

To close your dialog click on `IP Address` text.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [QustomDialog Source here](https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog) in your activity class (TestDialogActivity), you can set the "Ok" and "Cancel" button by setting the Negative and Positive button of the dialog like this:

```
private OnClickListener mShowDialogClickListener =new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        QustomDialogBuilder qustomDialogBuilder = new QustomDialogBuilder(v.getContext()).
                setTitle("Set IP Address").
                setTitleColor(HALLOWEEN_ORANGE).
                setDividerColor(HALLOWEEN_ORANGE).
                setMessage("You are now entering the 10th dimension.").
                setCustomView(R.layout.example_ip_address_layout, v.getContext()).
                setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        qustomDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        qustomDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /**
                 * Do something here...
                 */
            }
        });
        qustomDialogBuilder.show();
    }
};
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

Hope you'll find this helpful. Thanks!